# prove existence of a, such that a^2 = e

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

currently we have a $(G,*)$ group, which order is $2k$. Prove existence of non $e$ item $a$ in the group,  such that $a^2 = e$.
I am currently out of ideas, can you give me any hint. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to mathematics.SE. You should include your own thoughts/work on the problem, otherwise your question will just get closed. You should also use MathJax to format your question.

Comment: thanks for warm welcome Henrik. will do for next questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element of a group has a unique inverse.  The identity element is its own inverse.  So when you pair each element with its inverse, there must be at least one other element that gets paired with itself. Otherwise you'd have an odd number of elements in the group.

Comment: oh thanks. it was so obvious!  :D

Answer (score 0):

Since the order of the group is even and $2$ is a prime number, [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) tells us that it has an element of $G$ whose order is $2$.

Comment: Invoking Cauchy's theorem is just so way overkill here.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I fully agree. It's a good motivation for Cauchy's theorem, though.